# Load Events in Jquery Method from JSON string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, fullcalendar

I'm working in ASP.Net and c#. I have a JSON string that is posted to a webpage ("EventSource.aspx"). I'm trying to use the FullCalendar.js to fetch its information from this page.

My question is what do I do to EventSource.aspx so that it knows to hold the JSON available for FullCalendar?  The JSON is dynamically generated for each user so I can't simply save it to the database.

Here is sending the JSON (on Test.aspx.cs):

```
protected void SendJson(string json)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("EventSource.aspx");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }

}
```

Here is the html (on Test.aspx):

```
 <script>
     // The calendar needs to load the calendar data from a JSON string
     var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
         events: "EventSource.aspx"
     });
 </script>
 <div id="calendar"></div>
```

In between sending the JSON to EventSource.aspx and fetching it for the calendar Jquery method what needs to happen on EventSource.aspx?

EDIT:  Currently, EventSource.aspx is completely blank.  I don't know what to put there so that it holds and then passes on the JSON.  Should it be a Json page instead?  EventSource.json?

Comment: What does the code of eventsource.aspx do currently when it receives that JSON? An aspx page is normally a page which shows content to the user, rather than an endpoint which can receive json data from a separate request. Also, where are you sending the JSON _from_? Is that code in another part of your application, or from a different application? It's not really clear, we need more context. I'm wondering also if you've slightly misunderstood how web applications work. Remember that they're essentially stateless and that data doesn't persist between requests unless you store it somewhere.

Comment: @ADyson Sorry for the lack of context.  For now, all of the code above is on the same page.  So the html and Jquery method are on Test.aspx and the c# SendJson() method is on Test.aspx.cs.  Currently, nothing happens on EventSource.aspx, it's completely blank.  I'm very confused about how to get JSON from a c# method (on Test.aspx.cs) over to a Jquery method (on Test.aspx).  Reading FullCalendar's docs, the simplest way to load events is from a URL, but when FC visits the page at the specified URL, how does the page know to give the JSON to FullCalendar?  That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: ok. As i feared, this makes no sense. If you make a HTTP request from Test.aspx.cs to Test.aspx, that sends the JSON data to _a new instance of_ test.aspx. It doesn't somehow send it to your front-end in the browser. It's hard to explain in a short comment but basically you seem to have fundamentally misunderstood how asp.net (or web apps in general) works.

Comment: What you need to be doing, as I said in my first comment, is having a WebMethod within your page named something like `GetEvents`. In your fullCalendar code you'd set `events: "Test.aspx/GetEvents"` as the URL. This would mean that fullCalendar sends a HTTP request from the browser to that webmethod, and the webmethod must return the event data back to the browser by returning it from the method (asp.net takes care of the HTTP-related details). It doesn't do it by making a whole new request to a whole new copy of the same page (which is what you're doing now).

Comment: N.B. The WebMethod could also be within a  .asmx webservice or WCF .svc file, it doesn't have to be within the aspx, necessarily - depends how you want to design it. Actually here's a question from a while ago which I answered, with someone doing something quite similar. They ended up needing a custom events function to process the data structure coming back from the WCF service. Their app is in VB.NET rather than C# but all the structures, principles etc involved are the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287211/populate-fullcalendar-with-events-from-web-method

Comment: @ADyson Aha, okay I think I see what you mean.  Thanks for linking that page, that was helpful to look through.  I'll follow your advice and modify.